# How to change this specific color in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

[image: Image Visual Studio 2019]

Hi,
I am very new to coding and using Visual Studio, please no hate. I want to change the color of the text after the dot. I've drawn a red box around it. I played a bit around in Visual Studio but I cannot find the right display item under the Tools - Options - Font and Colors.

Does someone know the right display name so I can change the color to something a bit brighter?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can change color of the methods :

> Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts And Colors > Display Items > User Members - Metods

[image]